# ng-hide and ng-show without Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show, ng-hide

In order to hide and display some menus without using Javascript at all in AngularJS. I played around with ng-hide and ng-show like below.

```
<a ng-click="showmenu1=true">Menu 1</a>
<a ng-click="showmenu2=true">Menu 2</a>
<a ng-click="showmenu3=true">Menu 3</a>

<form ng-show="showmenu1">
  <label> 1 </label>
</form>

<form ng-show="showmenu2">
  <label> 2 </label>
</form>

<form ng-show="showmenu3">
  <label> 3 </label>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/39Lm68vj/4/

Updated question: how do you make menus 2 and 3 disappear while menu 1 is active?

Comment: At the minimum, you should use `ng-show`, not `ng-hide`...

Comment: What is expected behavior from all of these combined?

Comment: @charlietfl nothing shows until i click on each one

Comment: But do you want only one showing at a time?

Comment: `ng-click="showmenu=1"` and  `ng-show="showmenu==1"` repeat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to show one of these at a time you would be better off simplifying this down to using only one variable.

```
<a ng-click="toggleMenu(1)">Menu 1</a>
<a ng-click="toggleMenu(2)">Menu 2</a>
<a ng-click="toggleMenu(3)">Menu 3</a>

<form ng-show="model.showmenu == 1">
  <label> 1 </label>
</form>

<form ng-show="model.showmenu == 2" ng-cloak>
  <label> 2 </label>
</form>

<form ng-show="model.showmenu == 3" ng-cloak>
  <label> 3 </label>
</form>
```

then in controller

```
$scope.model = {
    showmenu:1
}

$scope.toggleMenu = function(val){
    $scope.model.showmenu = val;
}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/39Lm68vj/5/)**</kbd>

Comment: thank you but is there anyway to accomplish this without involving the controller?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to involve a controller? You would need to put things needlessly on rootscope and there is no point in doing that. Hiding variables in the view just makes testing more difficult

Comment: I feel like my controller already has too much stuff in it, seems messy

Comment: So use a separate controller or directive. Your reasoning is not sensible whatsoever. If controller is getting messy time to move a bunch of logic to service or start breaking up controller into other controllers or directives

Comment: Also can start running into child scope problems using that philosophy

Comment: thank you. What kind of child scope problems are you talking about?

Comment: suppose you put an `ng-repeat` on menu or the forms. Using a primitive variable in view only won't work due to child scopes that `ng-repeat` creates. Or if there was an `ng-if` in any of this, or `ng-include` or ....

Answer (score 2):

On `ng-click`, you need to apply the logic for changing states. Please have a look at `ng-init` (but it is better to avoid it)

```
<a ng-click="showmenu1=!showmenu1">Menu 1</a>
<a ng-click="showmenu2=!showmenu2">Menu 2</a>
<a ng-click="showmenu3=!showmenu3">Menu 3</a>

<form ng-hide="!showmenu1">
  <label> 1 </label>
</form>

<form ng-hide="!showmenu2">
  <label> 2 </label>
</form>

<form ng-hide="!showmenu3">
  <label> 3 </label>
</form>
```

here is live sample: http://jsfiddle.net/39Lm68vj/3/

Comment: however what if I want to make menu 2 and 3 disappear while menu 1 is active? Using the fiddle I provided?

Comment: thank you I see that you used ng-init here but mentioned in the response it is best to avoid it. Why avoid it?

Comment: @jebmarcus because it is performing "eval" for the expression

Comment: can you please clarify what it means to perform eval?

Comment: @jebmarcus this function http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp and the reason not to use it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/86580/5131537 and official documentation here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion

```
<a ng-click="menu=1">Menu 1</a>
<a ng-click="menu=2">Menu 2</a>
<a ng-click="menu=3">Menu 3</a>

<form ng-show="menu == 1">
  <label> 1 </label>
</form>

<form ng-show="menu == 2">
  <label> 2 </label>
</form>

<form ng-show="menu == 3">
  <label> 3 </label>
</form>
```